# How do I factor $z^4+2z^3+4z^2+2z+3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It seems so that I need help factoring this equation $z^4+2z^3+4z^2+2z+3$.

Both complex and real

Comment: One can spot the root $x=i$, so get $-i$ for free. The sum of the other two roots must be $-2$, and the product $3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing $z^4+2z^3+4z^2+2z+3$ with $(z^2+az+1)(z^2+bz+3)$ gives you $a=0,b=2$, namely,$$z^4+2z^3+4z^2+2z+3=(z^2+1) (z^2+2 z+3).$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I don't understand how you just did that

Comment: I thought $z^4+2z^3+4z^2+2z+3$ could be represented as $(z^2+az+1)(z^2+bz+3)$. Then, I compared $z^4+2z^3+4z^2+2z+3$ with $(z^2+az+1)(z^2+bz+3)=z^4+(b+a)z^3+(4+ab)z^2+(3a+b)z+3$. So, I had $2=b+a,4=4+ab,2=3a+b$, so I got $a=0,b=2$.

Comment: This was, basically, a lucky guess.  We assumed it could be factored in the integers and were right.  Also, since both the $z^4$ and the $z^0$ term were prime or even more restrictive than that, we were left with only one choice for possible values in front of the $z^2$ and $z^0$ terms in the two factors.

Comment: @CanH.Tartanoglu: You are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

You can notice how the coefficients show a palindrome-esque pattern. In that case, you can start by dividing and multiplying by $z^2$.
$$z^4+2z^3+4z^2+2z+3 $$After dividing and multiplying,$$z^2\left(z^2 + \dfrac{1}{z^2} + 2\left(z + \dfrac{1}{z}\right) + 4 \right) = z^2 \left(\left( z + \frac{1}{z}\right)^2 - 2 + 2\left(z  + \frac{1}{z}\right) + 4\right) $$If you let $t = z  + \frac{1}{z}$, the inner expression would reduce to a quadratic which you can solve.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular exercise you can also observe that

$$z^4+2z^3+4z^2+2z+3 =\left( z^4+4z^2+3 \right) +\left(2z^3+2z \right)$$

Each bracket is easy to factor as a product, and you get a common term.

Answer (score 0):

An elaboration of @mathlove's method, and also a slightly different (but still, of course, constructed) example.

Let's, instead of your expression, work on the expression $$2x^4-6x^3-15x^2-11x+3$$

### Rational Roots

Our first attempt involves something called The Rational Root Theorem, which says that any *linear* factor of this would be of the form $ax\pm b$, where $a$ is a factor of the highest order coefficient (2), and $b$ is a factor of the lowest order coefficient (3).  This gives us 8 possibilities: $(x+1)$, $(x-1)$, $(2x+1)$, $(2x-1)$, $(x+3)$, $(x-3)$, $(2x+3)$, $(2x-3)$.  None of those, sadly, work, so we have to move on.

### Double Quadratic

Now we have a couple of other things it could be.  In this we're still quite fortunate: 2 and 3 each only have one factorization in the integers.  If there were more, we'd have more possibilities.
$(2x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+3)$; $(2x^2+ax-1)(x^2+bx-3)$; $(2x^2+ax+3)(x^2+bx+1)$; $(2x^2+ax-3)(x^2+bx-1)$

Let's try expanding the first one to see what happens.

$$(2x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+3) = 2x^4 + ax^3 + 2bx^3 + 6x^2+abx^2+ x^2+3ax+bx+3$$
$$=2x^4+(a+2b)x^3+(7+ab)x^2+(3a+b)x+3$$
This suggests that we can find $a$ and $b$ that fit for the $x^3$ and $x$ terms, and then see if those values fit for the $x^2$ term.

$a+2b=-6$; $3a+b=-11$; $a=-16/5, b=-7/5$; $7+ab=287/25\ne-15$

So that doesn't work.  Let's try the others. I skipped a lot of the work so it's condensed:

$a+2b=-6$; $-3a-b=-11$; $a=28/5, b=-29/5$; $ab-7=-987/25\ne-15$

$a+2b=-6$; $a+3b=-11$; $a=4, b=-5$; $ab+5=-15$

Hey, that one worked!  Victory!  So our result is:
$$x^4-6x^3-15x^2-11x+3 = (2x^2+4x+3)(x^2-5x+1)$$